# Mongoose error handling for fetching by using findOne

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here in the below route I'm receiving user_id from url and fetching data from mongoDb using mongoose.
suppose my url looks like 'http://localhost/user/5eb47018d2ca374ea4cb36431' I'm getting desired result. But if I change the id value like '5eb47018d2ca374ea4cb36431234' it is returning server error. This is what I don't want to return. Instead this I like to return 'no user found'. How to handle the error in catch block to send desired message like 'user not found'.

forgive for wrong English.

```
  router.get('/user/:user_id', async(req, res) => {
      try {
          const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.params.user_id }).populate('user', ['name', 
          'avatar']);
          if (!profile) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No user for this profile' });
          res.json(profile);
         }catch (err) {
           console.error(err.message);
           res.status(500).send('Server Error');
        }
    });
```

Data in profile table

```
_id
:
5eb719425b385c31e475fa0d
skills
:
Array
0
:
"HTML"
1
:
"CSS"
2
:
"JS"
3
:
"PHP"
4
:
"JQUERY"
user
:
5eb47018d2ca374ea4cb3643
company
:
"xxxx"
website
:
"https://xxxx.xyz"
location
:
"xxxx"
bio
:
"Developer of this proect"
status
:
"developer"
githubusername
:
"notspecified"
social
:
Object
facebook
:
"https://facebook.com/xxxx"
twitter
:
"https://twitter.com/xxx"
experience
:
Array
date
:
2020-05-09T20:57:38.178+00:00
__v
:
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code inside `try` block check for `user_id` is valid ObjectId or not. If it is not valid Id it will throw error. So place this  `if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.userid)) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No user for this profile' });` inside your try block as below:

```
  router.get('/user/:user_id', async(req, res) => {
      try {

        if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.userid)) 
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No user for this profile' });

          const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.params.user_id }).populate('user', ['name', 
          'avatar']);
          if (!profile) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No user for this profile' });
          res.json(profile);
         }catch (err) {
           console.error(err.message);
           res.status(500).send('Server Error');
        }
    });
```

Parameter is checked for valid ObjectId before , if it is not a valid id just return desired response. And if it is valid then proceed further for checking it's availabilty.

Answer (score 1):

what is the type of user ? if the received id is the same of profile id try to use _id instead of user

Comment: It is refrenced from another schema. Everything is working fine but when I change the id parameter from 24 length to some other length it is giving  'error Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path yy.'. I need to catch this error in catch block so that last  statement 'res.status(500).send('Server Error');' do not execute instead of this send response like 'user not found'.

Comment: actually it crashes because it's not a valid MongoDB id and you only had a one catch block .so you can solve it by checking the length of the id before searching the database and if it's not valid id you just send a response with no user found or you can check in the catch block if error message ===  error Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path yy send no user found instead of server error

Comment: thanks it worked. I used an if statement to check whether it is valid id or not. If not a valid Id I'm not querying data from mongoDb.
if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.userid)) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No user for this profile' });